# background:none not working in ie7?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please tell me the foloowing css not applying in ie7.

I am erasing the default style of td in ie9,ie8 working fine using the below style.but in ie7 nothing is displaying  empty background is coming.

```
.tablesorter-tablesorter thead th 
   {
   background: none;
   }
```

In IE9,IE8 the above css is applying perfectly.

Please let me know..

Thanks,

Comment: `background: transparent;`

Comment: Do you try to remove a background based on an image ? If so you might try `background-image: none;` (edit : if it works on ie7, @adenao's answer is probably better)

Comment: Still supporting IE7.

Comment: Alternatively setting the background to a blank image or color works (Depending on the original background)

Comment: #background: none; and *background: none;

Comment: FWIW: [IE7 has 0.80% global market share](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0), even according to Net Applications, who tend to have higher IE numbers than others. ([StatCounter puts it at 0.23%](http://gs.statcounter.com/)) Of course, the only stats that really matter for your site are the ones for your site, just sayin'...

Comment: i want to remove default thead th styles.and i am applying thead tr style in page .so that i am using above css.in ie9,ie8 working but ie7 not working not showing the newly header style.

Comment: @user3494837 is background-color: #f00; working ???

Comment: @user3494837 you can also try filter:alpha(opacity=0)

Comment: if  i am individually giving the color name background-color:#f00 then styles are coming but i need to apply default th style to thead .but thead not reflecting the th style.default thead having one style,the old style is coming .i need to remove the default  thead style and apply new style.

Comment: @user3494837  , You are adding compatibility for IE 7 ?? Nice , Add compatibility for IE 6 ,IE 5 ,IE 4 ,IE 3 ,IE 2 ,IE 1 ,IE 0  !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try it this css all browser look likes...

```
.tablesorter-tablesorter thead th 
   {
   background: transparent;
   }
```